# Invert screen colors by *value*

Tags: linux, xorg, colors

How do I invert screen colors **by value**?

The most common way to invert colors is to use RGB-negation. Unfortunately, it's not very beautiful: blue becomes yellow, green becomes magenta, etc.

What I want is to invert `value`, one of the components among `hue` and `saturation`. This way, dark colors will become light, light become dark, but blue remains blue-ish anyway.

Example output (created with GIMP, doesn't work on the whole screen):

[image: orig]
=>
[image: value-inverted]

The goal is to have the entire screen "inverted", so you can read PDF-s, firefox, instant messaging -- all in dark colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution involving OpenGL-based compositors (compton, for example) and a custom made shader (*.glsl).

Here is the observation of the technique, along with the shader file: https://github.com/vn971/linux-color-inversion

Comment: // After ~3 years, I finally found a solution that works! Really happy. If you know the benefits of color inversion, I hope you like it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) tool with the [color-matrix option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#color-matrix):

> This option permits saturation changes, hue rotation, luminance to alpha, and various other effects. Although variable-sized transformation matrices can be used, typically one uses a 5x5 matrix for an RGBA image and a 6x6 for CMYKA (or RGBA with offsets). The matrix is similar to those used by Adobe Flash except offsets are in column 6 rather than 5 (in support of CMYKA images) and offsets are normalized (divide Flash offset by 255).
>
> As an example, to add contrast to an image with offsets, try this command:
>
> ```
> convert kittens.jpg -color-matrix \
>     " 1.5 0.0 0.0 0.0, 0.0, -0.157 \
>      0.0 1.5 0.0 0.0, 0.0, -0.157 \
>      0.0 0.0 1.5 0.0, 0.0, -0.157 \
>      0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0, 0.0,  0.0 \
>      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0, 1.0,  0.0 \
>      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0, 0.0,  1.0" kittens.png
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for inverting the whole screen area.. It's just for images.